# actionbarsherlock 4.3 and sliding menu integration

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

Working with the [sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) and the new [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html) I am having problems with the `jar mixmatch: Fix dependencies` for the sample project on the `sliding menu` to work on. Does anyone know what is going on ??

I also did see this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rs9mSnWDlZo), but still I am getting a very strange error. Help please. If there is another simple way to implement the *facebook* like `sliding menu` other than this library, please do post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actionbarsherlock has the support library in it. This probably causes a conflict if the support library is also in your main project.

Remove android-support-v4.jar  from your project's libs directory to solve the problem.

Comment: didn't work, I still have the sliding menu library that I am referencing to ... plus the example seems to be implementing its own jar file ... so all in all there are three separate jar files

Comment: does your sliding menu library also have have support library library. Remove the andorid-support-v4.jar from that and give it a try

Comment: oh my it worked ...thank you so so much. really happy that it finally did work.

Comment: This is because different version of jar files, you can place either ABS v4 jar file in the sample list or place sample list v4 jar file in abs, it will work fine. make sure both uses same version of jar

Answer (score 3):

please use this [link](https://github.com/akotoe/android-slide-out-menu.git)

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: how to use this as fragment means on on click of item call a new activity in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that both libs contain android-support-v4.jar (and maybe your own project too), and it should be in the build path only once. Put the jar into your own project, remove it from both lib-project's build path and edit their build paths to use the jar in your own project.

Comment: you are correct about the libs and the project too ... but how do I do the stuff you just mentioned ... a little more elaboration please ... very new to android.

Comment: So, now you have 3 projects, ownProject, sherlockProject and slidingProject. Delete android-support-v4.jar from slidingProject and sherlockProject, and if it is not there, put it into ownProject/libs folder. Open the build path of sherlockProject, and add ownProject/libs/android-support-v4.jar to it, repeat this to slidingProject and ownProject. Clean all projects.

Comment: or put the jar into sherlockProject/libs, and add it to the build path of sherlockProject and slidingProject like I wrote it above, and this way you won't have to put it inot ownProject's build path az it will be already included as sherlockProject is included as a library project to ownProject

Answer (score 0):

Both SlidingMenu and ActionbarSherlock can have their own support libraries in their own build paths as long as there is only one support library in main project's build path.

Check your project's Build Path/Libraries/Android Dependencies and there should only be one android-support-v4.jar file there (it does not matter from which project support library is imported). If there are duplicate support libraries, remove the extra ones from build path and give it a try that way.