# ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type, Jar mismatch : Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build

I am new to android development and also on Eclipse. Whenever I create an app it just gives errors

My Platform:

Android sdk-tools: 23.0.5
Android sdkplatform-tools: 21
Android sdkbuild-tools: 21.1

Errors:

```
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Versions found are:
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\Test\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test]    Length: 987314
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test]    SHA-1: 9b6a9a9078af571732159b904ad423b03b7cc786
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test]    Length: 758727
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Versions found are:
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\Test\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test]    Length: 987314
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test]    SHA-1: 9b6a9a9078af571732159b904ad423b03b7cc786
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test]    Length: 758727
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-11-03 15:58:24 - Test] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Versions found are:
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\Test\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test]    Length: 987314
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test]    SHA-1: 9b6a9a9078af571732159b904ad423b03b7cc786
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test]    Length: 758727
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Versions found are:
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\Test\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test]    Length: 987314
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test]    SHA-1: 9b6a9a9078af571732159b904ad423b03b7cc786
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test]    Length: 758727
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-11-03 15:58:35 - Test] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test] Versions found are:
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\Test\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test]    Length: 987314
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test]    SHA-1: 9b6a9a9078af571732159b904ad423b03b7cc786
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test] Path: C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test]    Length: 758727
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-11-03 15:58:47 - Test] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

First it was giving Errors of ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved , I tried to solve them by adding external jars and then these errors came

Comment: update your adt bundal

Comment: @Naveen Can you please explain how?

Comment: open sdk manager and updated android sdk tool

Comment: than uninsatll Adt from Eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt and than insatll adt

Comment: Already updated to 23.0.5

Comment: ok than uninsatll Adt from Eclipse stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt and than insatll adt

Comment: remove adt from eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt ans again install adt

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056914/jar-mismatch-fix-your-dependencies

Comment: I dont have the option in "Installed Software" of the ans you mentioned above, I have ADTPackage ? Uninstall it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting the jar file in work space will do the trick

> projectname>libs>android-support-v4

and go to

> appcompat_v7>libs>android-support-v4

copy this file and paste it in your project 
This process will help you bypass all the errors regarding this issue

Comment: Worked well with this project :), But I created a new project and it is giving me errors of ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved total of 9 errors , I previously fixed these by adding external jars. I have to do this for every project or there is a solution?

Comment: This is a temporary solution for each project i used to copy paste the jar files . Later i updated my ADT and SDK i never faced such kind of problem so far.Updating the ADT and re-installing Sdk's will do the trick. **This is a temporary quick fix**

Comment: Can you please explain what should I do now?

Comment: Just update your ADT and install any new tools available in sdk manager.

Comment: Always remember you must be having the sdk tools for that particular version of android for targeting.So dont delete any sdk tools when you update to new one and always check the version you are targeting with your available sdk tools

Comment: Thankyou :) yeap helped alot