# Export and then import the Android project into a new Eclispe workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

I wanted just to learn how export and import works in Eclispe before sending the Android projects to other person.

The project works fine, contains 3 folders `appcompat_v7, busTracker, and google-play-services_lib`, has the following SDK Location `D:\andriod_sdk`. I exported the folders   by performing the following steps:

Selected the 3 directories → Export → General, Archive File → provide the path → Finish.

Next, I imported the exported project into new Eclipse workspace by doing the following:

File → Import → General → Existing Projects into Workspace → Next → Select archive file → Finish.

But I am getting to many errors in the new Eclispe workspace, I think it does not recognize the SDK Location. Please see the screensht below.

I verified the SDK Location  in the new Eclipse workspace (where I have imprted the exported folders) by performing the following steps Window → Preferences → Android →  SDK Location. And there I have the same SDK path `D:\andriod_sdk` of the orginal project.

[image]

Comment: WHY? Why do you want to use eclipse? The support is dropped by Google.

Comment: because I implemented the project with Eclipse.

Comment: I would move to Android Studio and gradle. This makes your life much easier.

Comment: @rekire: Is not it possible to manage the problem in Eclipse since I have finished the project but next time I will use Android Studio?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that I have no idea how to fix this issue. I used eclipse the last time years ago.

Comment: you need to add support library to project

Comment: @piotrek1543: Which support library do u mean and how can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound like you imported the library right... Check your build tools version and do as below:

**1. ANDROID SDK BUILD TOOLS LOWER THAN 22.1.0**

In eclipse you need to **right click on the project**, go to **Properties**, select **Android** in the list then **Add** to add the library

Follow this tutorial in the docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

---

**2. ANDROID SDK TOOLS HIGHER THAN 22.1.0**

Since the version 22.1.0, the class **ActionBarActivity** is deprecated, so instead use **AppCompatActivity**.
For more details [see here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

1 - Make sure library project(appcompat_v7) is open & is proper referenced (added as library) in your application project.

2 - Delete android-support-v4.jar from your project's libs folder(if jar is present).

3 - Appcompat_v7 must have android-support-v4.jar &  android-support-v7-appcompat.jar inside it's libs folder.
   (If jars are not present copy them from /sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs folder of your installed
     android sdk location)

4- Check whether ActionBarActivity is properly imported.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

3. IF ABOVE SOLUTIONS  NOT WORK

(From: [ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type, Jar mismatch : Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712932/actionbaractivity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-jar-mismatch-eclipse)):

> Deleting the jar file in work space will do the trick
>
> ```
>      projectname>libs>android-support-v4
> ```
>
> and go to
>
> ```
>      appcompat_v7>libs>android-support-v4
> ```
>
> copy this file and paste it in your project  This process will help
>   you bypass all the errors regarding this issue

Hope it help