# "Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies" error appears every new android project

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the following errors every time create a new android application project

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time). All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time. Versions found are: workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar workspace\TreeSmart\libs\android-support-v4.jar Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I know that just deleting the jar file from the project's lib folder will remove the errors but do i have to do that every damn time i create a new project?

Can this be permanently fixed no?
I'm new to android development

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056914/jar-mismatch-fix-your-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same version of library in your projects. If not, take one version of the library and use the same in other project.